In R, creating a new column in dataframe that increments based on the value of one column and resets based on the value of another
I have a table that looks something like this:
subject  amount

1        12
1        12
1        24
2        10
2        10
3        8
3        8
3        9
3        10
4        16
5        13
5        13
5        13
5        27
5        29  
6        23
6        23 


I want to have it such that I add a new column to the dataframe which has a running count that increases by 1 when the amount changes and resets when the subject changes:
subject  amount   Count 

1        12        1
1        12        1
1        24        2
2        10        1
2        10        1
3        8         1
3        8         1
3        9         2
3        10        3
4        16        1 
5        13        1
5        15        2
5        15        2
5        27        3
5        29        4
6        23        1
6        23        1


I tried doing something similar to the answer seen here: Increment by 1 for every change in column but this only works based on the data from one column so it does not apply to what I am looking for.

Welcome to R and SO! Are you familiar with the tidyverse? My suggestion would be to make an intermediate table with unique values and a count within each group.
df_to_pivot = df1 |>  distinct() |>   group_by(subject) |> mutate(C = 1:n() ) and with a join: df1 |> left_join(df_to_pivot, by = c("subject","amount"))

df |> mutate(count = cumsum(amount != lag(amount,1,0)), .by = subject)?

Using consecutive_id paired with grouping gives the desired result
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Count = consecutive_id(amount), .by = subject)
   subject amount Count
1        1     12     1
2        1     12     1
3        1     24     2
4        2     10     1
5        2     10     1
6        3      8     1
7        3      8     1
8        3      9     2
9        3     10     3
10       4     16     1
11       5     13     1
12       5     13     1
13       5     13     1
14       5     27     2
15       5     29     3
16       6     23     1
17       6     23     1


We can use cumsum and diff with mutate/.by or ave
# 1 - tidyverse
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(Count = cumsum(c(1, diff(amount) != 0)), .by = subject)

# 1a - with lag
dat %>%
  mutate(Count = cumsum(amount != lag(amount, 1, first(amount) - 1)),
    .by = subject)


# 2 - base R
dat |>
  transform(Count = ave(amount, subject, FUN = \(x) cumsum( c(1, diff(x) != 0) )))


Thank you so much for this! I was able to do the dplyr version and get the answers I wanted. I am curious if you would not mind clarifying what the diff(amount) != 0 is doing in this function?

If y <- diff(x) then y[i] = x[i+1]-x[i] for i = 1, 2, .., (length(x)-1)
